# Java - Replace single element with multiple elements from list

Tags: java, collections

I want to replace single object from `List<String>` with multiple objects.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ROLL_NO","FULL_NAME","PERCENTAGE", "ADDRESS"));
```

I want to replace "FULL_NAME" with "FIRST_NAME" AND "LAST_NAME". So my list elements will be like as

```
"ROLL_NO",
"FIRST_NAME", 
"LAST_NAME",
"PERCENTAGE", 
"ADDRESS"
```

`Collections.replaceAll()` method replaces with single object only.

Is there a better way with java8 stream?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just remove and insert?

Comment: It is better if you create a class such as `Person` to hold all the attributes. Right now, you have no way to ensure the data integrity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `FULL_NAME` element and replace it with the `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` elements:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ROLL_NO","FULL_NAME","PERCENTAGE", "ADDRESS")); 

    int index = list.indexOf("FULL_NAME");

    list.remove(index); //remove "FULL_NAME"

    list.add(index, "LAST_NAME");
    list.add(index, "FIRST_NAME");
```

Note the order which I am adding them. First `LAST_NAME` and then `FIRST_NAME`. This is done as setting an element at in index shifts the current element at that index to the right of the list. By doing so the elements are in the correct order as you suggested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you can use `remove()` and `add()`. But a better approach will be creating a class to hold all those attributes:

```
public class Person{
    private String rollNo;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double percentage;
    private String double;

    //your constructors, getters & setters
}
```

Then use an `ArrayList` to hold various `Person` object together as one collection:

```
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This way, whenever you need to add/remove a record as a whole, there is no need to add/remove all related attributes manually which is very prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If you list is mutable, you can use a `listIterator` to accomplish the same thing.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var values = new ArrayList<>(List.of(args));
        final var it = values.listIterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            final var value = it.next();

            if ("FULL_NAME".equals(value)) {
                it.remove();

                it.add("FIRST_NAME");
                it.add("LAST_NAME");
            }
        }
    }
}
```